# Industry Term for "Intentional production halt" department

Tags: word-choice

Is there a name for when production is stopped intentionally in order to allow the factory to perform repairs and maintenance?

Comment: Maintenance window or planned down-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *scheduled down-time.*

The phrase will leave three impressions:

1. currently not in operation
2. not broken or defective
3. operation will resume at some "scheduled time"

Comment: Sounds good. I had come across "down-time" but it sounded negative.

Answer (score 1):

In Australian usage the term *planned outage* is common.

See, for example, [this page by Ergon Energy](https://www.ergon.com.au/outages--and--disruptions/planned-outages), where they publish a list of upcoming planned outages for the electricity distribution network.

> In order to keep the network functioning and carry out necessary maintenance and upgrades, sometimes we need to interrupt the supply of power. However, our aim is to minimise the impact of any outage that may affect you.
>
> Except in emergencies, if an upgrade or maintenance to the network requires us to interrupt supply, we will notify you at least two business days before the *planned outage*.
>
> The date and the estimated start and finish times of the *planned outage* will be sent to you by mail, letterbox drop, newspaper or radio advertisement, email, phone, fax, or flyer.

Informally, this is often shortened to the single word *outage*.

> You'll need to *arrange an outage* before you can repair that machine.

Comment: TIL, but mine was for a friend's resume, she works in the oil industry.